# Are there any potential issues with setting super() to a class attribute?

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass

I've slightly changed the way I use `super` as I've got a little more familiar with it, and each time I've found an issue. I'm still having to use Python 2.7 so the old syntax is necessary.

Two of the alternate ways I've tried and stopped using are `super(self.__class__, self)` and `InheritClass.func(self, ...)`.

I realised that `super` basically returns an object, so instead of constantly creating the object, it could be assigned to a class attribute instead. It seems a little neater as the instance is only needed to be read once, but would there be any potential issues arising over this.

I've been setting it to `self.__super` so nothing can really interfere with it, I'd just like an opinion before I do too much and have to rewrite a whole load of code.

Comment: Your title says "class attribute", but `self.__super` is an instance attribute. But more importantly, you haven't shown us *what* you assign to that attribute, so we can't tell you if it's wrong or right.

Comment: Theres potential issues with messing with any internal functions, why are you doing it at all?

Comment: I mean using `self.__super = super(MyClass, self)`, then just using `self.__super` every time you need to inherit a method

Comment: Well initially, what happens when you inherit from an inherited class?

Comment: You may need to add extra bits to a method but still call it from the inherited class. In my case, I've overridden a ton of methods, where it will only use the inherited method if the window is in a certain state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with assigning a `super` object to an instance attribute is that it creates a reference cycle:

```
import weakref

class RefCycle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__super = super(RefCycle, self)

obj = RefCycle()

ref = weakref.ref(obj)
del obj
assert ref() is None  # <- assertion fails, the object still exists
```

Of course the garbage collector will detect and clean up this reference cycle *eventually*, but if you get into a habit of using `super` like this, you *will* be wasting a significant amount of memory.

A better solution is to implement a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that returns a `super` object:

```
class NoRefCycle(object):
    @property
    def __super(self):
        return super(NoRefCycle, self)
```

This way, no reference cycles are created.

Comment: Ah thanks for the info, yeah that definitely sounds bad on larger projects. The property is a good idea, but as it's still recreating the object, I guess I might as well stick with the traditional method :)